# Swapping duplicates from different arrays

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, arraylist, sudoku

I have three multidimensional arrays of [3][3] each.

I need to make sure that there aren't any duplicates on each row or colum, but each individual [3][3] array maintains it's numbers which are 1 through 9.

Example

```
[9,5,7] [1,8,7] [9,2,3] 
[4,1,2] [2,6,5] [1,8,6]
[8,6,3] [3,4,9] [7,4,5]
```

I should be able to change it to:

```
[9,5,7] [1,8,2] [4,6,3] 
[4,1,2] [7,6,5] [9,8,2]
[8,6,3] [3,4,9] [7,1,5]
```

Note how the numbers have been swapped so that all three rows have unique numbers and all three arrays of [3][3] still maintain it's numbers 1-9

### I have tried two different ways

1) To swap/shuffle numbers until the sum of every row is 45 (numbers 1-9 added gives 45)

2) To add to ArrayLists the dupes as I ask array by array

I have to add that every multidimensional array of [3][3] has been added using the Collections method with numbers 1-9.

Comment: I would add the _Sudoku_ tag ;)

Comment: Just did, sorry kind of new :)

Comment: solution #1, is not quite robust, since 45 could be done, in other ways of combinations.

Comment: Correct it it didn't work out. the second on does work, and it identifies it but only for the second Array.

Comment: I wonder if you could assign values to each of the numbers, 1-9, so that they will sum to a particular value *only* if the numbers 1-9 are used without repetition. Perhaps if they are primes?

Comment: Didn't quite grasp that. Could you repeat that again pls?